# Mysql Update query with varchar field in the where condition not working

Tags: mysql

I have a wiered Issue the update Query

```
UPDATE tablename set `round3`=0 where `player` LIKE'%playername%';
```

Is not getting updated using the php script. But when I copy the query and manually insert it using the phpmyadmin Query interface its getting updated. Somebody please help me to fix this.

Comment: Please show the PHP code that is building/executing the SQL query.

Comment: check syntax. May be syntax error.

Comment: put your PHP code here instead of only query.

Comment: Its
$sql="UPDATE `tablename` set `round3`=".$data[1]." where `player` LIKE'%playename%'";
   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Your php code please. You are probably doing mistake while executing your query in the next step. using wrong variable for query or connection variable

Comment: There is no much code int eh page Iam reading the csv file and updating the table

Comment: I checked the connection and the resource id is getting printed. The weird thing is no error is getting outputted.

Comment: There is playename and playername (difference of r) in your two query posts?

Comment: Have you used this mysql_query($sql)

Comment: Thats just a dummy data . the actual is a name ex:MCILROY

Comment: If a varchar field is used in " where condition" is it needed to type cast?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to be accurate without seeing the entire query, but I think you are missing something in your UPDATE
Try

```
UPDATE tablename set `round3`=0 where `player` LIKE'%$playername%';
```